# Character for Game Engine not working

Tags: mesh, game-engine, objects, physics

I am making a game where you walk around and gather items from various gathering spots. My initial problem was that my rigid body player was not colliding with my static plant model, then I thought to make my player a character physics type.

However, once I changed the physics, it no longer collided with my floor plane properly, and when I press a key to move the player, the motion does not stop (it is perpetual motion).

I've attached both of my `.blend` files. the first is with a rigid body physics type and the second is with character.

Here are the files: [Rigid Body](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Wxv8rERLZCNzdrZ2s4LUwwUzg),
 [Character](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Wxv8rERLZCU1FONFJidy1zUGM)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue but I will leave this up in case someone else has my problem.

To solve this keep the player as rigid body type and change the armature attached to a sensor physics type. Remember to add collision bounds to the armature and ensure that detect actors is checked on the armature and that the static object you wish to collide with is set as an actor (don't worry the armature will not collide with the model its attached to.)

Thank you to anyone who tried to help me and I hope that I saved someone some time fixing their game.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! Could you please accept your own answer so that it is easier to find for others that run into similar problems?